# How to print the contents of a character array in the main function whose base address is returned by a function through a character pointer?

Tags: c++, arrays, string, loops, pointers

I was trying to print the contents of a character array in the main function by accepting the base address of that array in a character pointer which is returned by another function. Actually here the code is to accept a string with vowels and return the modified string without vowels.
But when i print the character array in the main function, the code does not print anything.
It is possible to do with a string class though but i want to know what is the problem while using character pointers.

```
    #include<iostream>
    #include<string.h>
    using namespace std;
    char * print(char * s)
    {
        int j=0,len;
        while(s[j]!='\0')
           j++;
        len=j;
        char scopy[len];
        char * sn;
        j=0;
        for(int i=0;i<len;i++)
        {
            if(s[i]!='a' && s[i]!='e' && s[i]!='i' && s[i]!='o' && s[i]!='u' && s[i]!='A' && s[i]!='E' && s[i]!='I' && s[i]!='O' && s[i]!='U')
            {
                scopy[j]=s[i];
                j++;
            }
        }
        sn=scopy;
        return sn;
    }
    int main()
    {
        int n;
        cout<<"enter n:\n";
        cin>>n;
        char st[n];
        cout<<"enter string:\n";
        cin>>st;
        char * ps=print(st);
        cout<<"the string is\n"<<ps[0]<<ps[1]<<ps[2]<<"\n";  //Here when i print the array contents individually using the base pointer, it prints successfully
        for(int i=0;ps[i]!=NULL;i++)  //the problem is here, it does not print anything
           cout<<ps[i];
    }
```

Comment: You have two problems: The first is that you do not terminate the string. The second is that you return a pointer to a local array which will go out of scope and disappear immediately you do `return`.

Comment: You really should be using `std::string` here. Much easier to use, and avoids all the difficulties you are having.

Answer (score 0):

Your code invokes *Undefined Behavior*, because it returns a pointer to a local variable, which will go out of scope as soon as the function will terminate:

```
char * print(char * s)
{
    ...      
    char scopy[len];
    char * sn;
    ...
    sn=scopy;
    return sn;
}
```

Moreover, you do *not* null-terminate the string, and then you do:

```
for(int i=0; ps[i]!=NULL ;i++)
     cout << ps[i];
```

`ps` is not null terminated, thus `ps[i] != NULL` will be always true.

---

Since you are using C++, I strongly recommend using [`std::string`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/), and not C-style strings.

Comment: You are welcome @Sajeed786. You can *accept* my answer if it helped.